# remove required property from input field on form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-4

Model:

```
[Display(Name = "City"]
[Required]
[RegularExpression(@"^(?!\d$).*$"]
[StringLength(20,MinimumLength = 2]
public string City { get; set; }
```

Form:

```
@Html.LabelFor(x => x.City, new { @class = "control-label" })
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.City, new {id="city" })
```

Script:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {   
    $("#identificationForm").submit(function (e) {
      var required=document.getElementById("city").required;
      console.log(required);
      // e.preventDefault();
     });
  });
</script>
```

I want to remove required property if some condition is met.Unable to do this this way.How can i achieve this?

Comment: With Jquery: $("#city").removeAttr("required"); or use document.getElementById("city").removeAttribute('required');

Comment: Are you using JqueyVal? If yes, removing the required isn't the only thing!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set HTML5 required attribute in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18770369/how-to-set-html5-required-attribute-in-javascript)

Answer (score 60, accepted):

JavaScript is case sensitive.

Use

```
document.getElementById("city").required = false;
```

[Demonstration](http://jsbin.com/emozik/1/edit)

Be careful that your code can't work as you try to access the element before it exists. Put your script after the element if you don't execute the code on an event :

```
<input type="text" id="city" required>
<script>
if(somecondition is true){
    document.getElementById("city").required = false;
}
</script>
```

Note also that you can't change this in a submit function and expect your form to be submitted because it's too late : this event handler won't be called if the required field is not filled !

Comment: Form is still not submitting and i am doing this in form submit function

Comment: @user2137186 I've edited my answer to point another problem. It may be relevant or not, depending on how far the code you show is from what you really have.

Comment: I am call that script function on form submit function

Comment: But is your submit function called ? If required is true and the field empty, then it shouldn't be called. You must change it elsewhere, from example by binding to a button click event.

Comment: @dystroy Given that he's using MVC4, maybe exists a JqueryVal. So removing the required isn't enougth.

Comment: This does normally work but not with the data annotations.

Answer (score 18):

You can use:

```
document.getElementById("city").removeAttribute("required");
```

or with jQuery

```
$('#city').removeAttr('required')
```

Comment: Form is still not submitting and i am doing this in form submit function

Comment: well i am using .net mvc4 ...so this should not be posted here

Comment: @user2137186 you can post, just! We will reflag it for mvc as well!

Answer (score 5):

You shoud do this:

```
if(somecondition is true)
{
  var city = document.getElementById("city");
  city.removeAttribute('required');
}
```

Comment: Form is still not submitting and i am doing this in form submit function

Comment: You should post the entire function.

Comment: what do you mean by that?

Comment: You should post the entire form, and the function, theres something else wrong!

Answer (score 1):

By the time the `On Submit` function is to remove the required attribute, the form would have already passed validation. The steps are first you have to disable validation then you will be able to submit the form with the required fields empty. Next remove the required attributes and finally manually invoke validation via `$.validator.unubtrusive.parse(form)` and this will now validate the form by invoking the other validation types such as `string length` and `formatting`, everything else except the required attributes. Check `if form.valid() then submit() else` do nothing.

Answer (score 1):

In php its very easy, this will not validate your form while submitting,

```
<input type="submit" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')" value="Abort Test" formnovalidate>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if anyone has figured out a better way to do this yet and it might not be the most efficient way to do it but you could use PHP to get this done. If the condition you are looking to meet is known before the page loads then you can have this:

```
<input type="text" id="city" 

<?php
     if (condition_is_met) {
          echo ">";
     } else {
          echo "required>";
     }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you put your text fields in a form, it is possible to overwrite the required field with a special attribute called ***novalidate***. This is the syntax: `<form novalidate> .. </form>`

Here is an example:

```
<form novalidate>
  Zip code: <input type="text" name="zipcode" pattern="[0-9]{5}" required><br/>

  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

[The novalidate Attribute](https://www.wufoo.com/html5/novalidate-attribute/?num=) Here is a link with two live demos using ***novalidate*** attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Or in the moment that form is submitted you can disabled it if it's null:

`if($("#City").val().trim().length == 0)
    $("#City").attr("disabled", true);`

Answer (score 0):

This works for me with data annotations.  Use the "rules" function.

```
$("#FileUpload").rules("remove", "required");
```

and to add:

```
$("#FileUpload").rules("add", "required");
```

UPDATE: This will fix frontend validation but backend validation still fails.  To make the ModelState valid, I change the ValidationState of that input.

```
ModelState["FileUpload"].ValidationState = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.ModelValidationState.Valid;
```

I do check to make sure that's the only error too:

```
if (ModelState["FileUpload"].Errors.Count == 1)
    if (ModelState["FileUpload"].Errors[0].ErrorMessage.Equals("The FileUpload field is required."))
        ModelState["FileUpload"].ValidationState = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.ModelValidationState.Valid;
```